# object != null verification

Tags: java

Is this verification whether the object passed null or not is OK or I should use a kind of equals() methods?

```
public void addCard(Card card) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (card != null){
            cardList.add(card);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I prefer to do it like this:

```
/**
 * Adds a card to the deck.
 *
 * @param the card to add.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the card is null.
 */
public void addCard(final Card card) 
{
    if(card == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("card must not be null");
    }

    cardList.add(card);
}
```

1. it is less code to read
2. it separates the error condition from the expected condition (no else = no indent)
3. nobody needs to see what is on line X to see that the card variable was null = less time for people searching to find out what they did wrong.
4. no need to clutter the code with useless throws statements - you should javadoc it though with an @throws clause

Other than that, you are doing it right, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Not sure if I got the 4th statement. Do you mean I don't have to throw an exception here?

Comment: @AndroidNoob - You need to throw the exception, you just don't need to *declare* that you throw it. `public void addCard(Card card)` by itself is enough, because IllegalArgumentException is a RuntimeException.

Comment: @DJClayhworth - lol!  Jon and I used to tour the Java new groups way back when... as it was I didn't see the answer Jon gave until now - but I agree with him!

Answer (score 21):

That's correct, but personally I'd structure it the other way round. It's common to validate arguments at the start of the method, and then use them for the rest of the method knowing they're correct:

```
public void addCard(Card card) {
    if (card == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attempt to add null card");
    }
    cardList.add(card);
}
```

The benefit of doing all the argument testing up-front is that if an invalid argument is passed to you, you'll throw an exception before any side-effects have taken place - rather than half way through the method, which could leave the object in an invalid state. Of course in this case it doesn't matter, but I favour consistency here :)

Note that there's no need to declare `IllegalArgumentException` - it's a subclass of `RuntimeException`, which means it's unchecked (you don't need to declare it).

Comment: +1: having the tests at the top is also some kind of documentation

Answer (score 6):

Effective Java from Josh Blosh recommends the following:

```
/**
 * ads a card to card list.
 * 
 * @param card card to add. Can not be null
 * 
 */
public void addCard(Card card) {
      if (card == null) {
           throw new NullPointerException("Card can not be null")
      }  
      cardList.add(card);
    }
```

So, firstly you do not declare the RuntimeException. Secondly you throw a NullPointerException because your argument is not simply incorrect - it is null. Thirdly, you specify the arguments in javadoc, can they be null or not.

Comment: A NullPointerException is ever a bug. A IllegalArgumentException is better.

Comment: @Horcrux7 : Joshua Bloch disagrees with you, and passing a `null` to the addCard method **is** a bug, as is documented in the method contract - via the @param statement "Can not be null"

Comment: Interesting use of NullPointerException.  I was dubious, until I checked the javadoc of NPE and it actually states that "Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object."

Comment: @Stephen-P: Passing the null to the addCard is of course also bug. The coding rules in my company forbid a new NullPointerException. And I think this is good so. A NPE in Java is like a access violation in C.

Comment: I prefer IllegalArgumentException over NullPointerException because it is clear that the argument had an unexpected value.  You should also have an @throws NullPointerException if the card is null.  That also means the @param comment about null should go away.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`Validate`](http://people.apache.org/~bayard/commons-lang-3.0-snapshot-api/org/apache/commons/lang/Validate.html) class. It makes your code shorter and simpler:

```
public void addCard(Card card) {
    Validate.notNull(card);
    cardList.add(card);
}
```

It will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with a default message (you can pass a custom message as a 2nd argument, if you like)

Answer (score 3):

As you are comparing the reference you should use `!=`. Using `equals` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to verify if cards being added are not `null`, your code will work fine.  You just need to make sure to handle the `IllegalArgumentException` when you call `addCard`.

Comment: You shouldn't handle the exception - you should simply avoid passing in null. IllegalArgumentException should pretty much *never* be caught explicitly.

Comment: That's a good point.  My main point was that this would be enough of a check to validate.  I just think it is usually better to handle these exceptions so the user does not see a crashing application, but it depends on the situation.